# Group posts view

Tags: views, organic-groups

I am struggling to make a view to display the posts of a group. I have done the filter and chosen the fields I want to display, but I am struggling with the arguments. I am not sure what the path would be, if I want the view to be a tab of the group node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this contextual filter:

- "(Organic groups group) Organic groups group: Entity id"

and have these 2 relationships added:

- "Group membership: Node group membership"
- "(group membership) OG membership: Group gid"

This will show the nodes that belong to your group. Sorry, I can't help you on the "tab question".

Make sure to checkout this awesome [OG video tutorial](http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups).

Comment: mototribe to the rescue as per usual. thanks for all your help. I will give it a shot :)