# How to filter a node reference field in content type form

Tags: 7, entities

I have a node reference field (User groups) in my content type; i would like to apply a filter on that field to show only the Groups belonged to the current user.
How can i apply that filter in the content type insert/edit form?

Answer (score 1):

I've written [step by step instructions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/how-to-create-basic-organic-groups-functionality-with-flags-and-references) on how to do that.

Your setup will be a bit different since you don't use flags. "Step 3" describes how to use the "views reference" feature to show the referenced nodes on your node/add,edit page using views.