# Where to start for implementing user roles/levels?

Tags: users, organic-groups

I have three types of user roles in my site:

- department heads.
- department managers.
- employees.

There are several department heads. Each Department Head manages multiple department managers. And each Department manager manages multiple employees.

What I want is:

- Department managers should be able to see details of THEIR employees.
- Department heads should be able see THEIR managers and the employees working under each of these managers.

There are lots of techniques/solutions on roles and permissions. Such as those provided by specific contributed modules (including [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)). But I am confused which one to start with.

Anybody can shed some light about this?

Comment: Sounds like you want http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole at least to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)** module (a new module as of D7). It should address most (if not all) of your requirements. And it offers a potential alternative to the **[Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)** module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> **[Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)** allows content itself to be groups, which isn't always what people want. It relies on an entity reference field to keep track of the ties between a group (node, term, ...) and its content (node, term, user, ...).
>
> **[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)** instead creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. Every group can have users, roles and permissions attached to it. Groups can also act as a parent of any type of entity. Seeing as a group itself is also an entity, creating subgroups is very easy.

Some major differences between these 2 modules are:

- **Group** started in D7 only, taking full advantage of entities introduced in D7.
- **Organic Groups** is commonly perceived as a huge module, which carries a lot of "legacy" from pre-D7 releases.
- A D8 version of **Group** is in the pipeline and actively being worked on these days (expectation is "only a few months from now").

## Additional Group sub-modules

Extra features can be enabled via these sub-modules:

- **[Group Add](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/modules/gadd)**: Add members to a group without their consent.
- **[Subgroup](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/modules/ggroup)**: Make group to belong to another group.
- **[Group Invite](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/modules/ginvite)**: Allow group members to invite people into their group.
- **[Group Node](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/modules/gnode)**: Enables Group functionality for the Node module.
- **[Group member profiles](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/group/tree/modules/gprofile)**: Create multiple fieldable member profiles, which can be attached to a member.

Have a look at my answer to "[How to create basic Organic Groups functionality with flags and references?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/how-to-create-basic-organic-groups-functionality-with-flags-and-references/190305#190305)" for way more details about it, such as available integration with other (commonly used) modules.