# How to show organic groups users that their subscription is pending?

Tags: organic-groups

I'm using the [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) (=OG) module. When a user subscribes to an OG they just see "Unsubscribe from group", even if they are not yet members, but their membership is pending. What is the best way to display a message such as "Thanks for your subscription request, it is currently being considered." or something like that?

Note: I have quite a number of questions related to Organic Groups but this is the best place I have found or support. If you can suggest other sources of OG support I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for this is to use a combination of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) modules, which integrate very well with the [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module.

Here are the highlights of how you could make it work:

1. Create a 'global' flag (using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)) that will be used to identify (flag) users with their membership is pending
2. Create a 1st rule (using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)) like so:

   - Rules Event = User has become a group member
   - Rules Condition = `og-membership:state` EQUAL TO `pending`
   - Rules Action = set the flag (defined as in "1.") the user (using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag))
3. Create a 2nd rule (using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)) like so:

   - Rules Event = User has become a group member
   - Rules Condition = `og-membership:state` EQUAL TO `active`
   - Rules Action = unset the flag (defined as in "1.") the user (using [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag))
4. Create a 3rd rule (using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)) like so:

   - Rules Event = Content is viewed
   - Rules Condition = *"Path matches some path on which you want to show such message"*
   - Rules Action = Show a message on the site

In case you have multiple organic groups for which you want to implement something similar, you have these options:

- Create a similar flag and a similar set of 3 rules for each of these groups.
- Use the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module so that you can combine the above logic for all groups in an enhanced version of rule2, -3 and -4.
- It would probably also be a good idea to move part of the logic in the above rules in a 'rules component'.

Using the [Rules Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module you could also combine rule 2 and rule 3 above in a single rule.

In case the above may seem like overkill (2 extra modules, and 3 rules to be created ...), keep in mind that with these very same 2 modules you can implement lots (dozens?) of other functions/features. Probably also to address "*... quite a number of questions related to Organic Groups*..." you mentioned in your question.

## Video tutorials

If you're not familiar with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework). And/or the similar [set of 8 video tutorials](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-flag) about the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. For [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) there is another set of amazing videos to [Learn Organic Groups](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-organic-groups).

## Possible alternative

For anybody who considers the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module as rather complex (like me ...), have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module as a possible alternative. For (way) more details about this module, refer to my answer to "[How to create basic Organic Groups functionality with flags and references?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/how-to-create-basic-organic-groups-functionality-with-flags-and-references/190305#190305)".

Comment: Thank you very much for  your detailed answer. It does seem very complicated for something that I would have thought would be a very common requirement! I am reasonably familiar with both Rules and Flag, I'll try this out. OG is interesting but does seem extremely complex for the functionality it adds - although perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: That looks interesting, although it makes me nervous that there is only one developer...

Comment: I'm no longer using organic groups as  it proved to be too complex for what I required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback James. You're not the only one who things OG is (way too) complex. That's probably why more and more people start to consider/use the "group" module as an alternative for it ... So just in case you ever have an OG-like requirement again, keep that module in mind "too" ...