# How to limit search results based only on OG group membership?

Tags: 7, search, organic-groups, views

I followed the tutorial about [How to Create Custom Search Pages Using Just Views in Drupal 7](http://www.webwash.net/drupal/videos/how-create-custom-search-pages-using-just-views-drupal-7).

I have selected the blocks option instead of page option in views as I want to add it as a block in the organic group homepage.

How do I restrict the search using **relationship and context filtering** in the Views settings so each logged in user can only search for published content of their group only **(NOT SITE-WIDE)**?

**EDIT:** I have already tried the following:

Contextual filters > (OG membership from node) OG membership: Group ID
Relationships > OG membership: OG membership from Node

(Which I got the idea from the default og_content view that comes with OG Groups!)

Can this be done with hooks?

Comment: As per your (3rd) comment like "*I personally think OG is ...*" below the answer: are you aware that there is a possible alternative for OG these days? Not sure (yet) if it would help to actually build such Views based search. Let me know if you want me to post an answer about that alternative.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I know there is a "Group" module (https://www.drupal.org/project/group) as well... I am eager to learn as much as possible on different alternatives so please do share your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Editing my answer here as there seems to be a glitch in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Even with no contextual filters or relationships, just filtering by groups audience and exposed search doesn't work. The SQL query has both values but I don't know enough about sql to debug it.

> 1. Contextual filters > (OG membership from node) OG membership: Group ID
> 2. Relationships > OG membership: OG membership from Node

Instead, here's a hacky way of getting it to work by not using the search module.

1. Do the same as above to limit results by group.
2. If you only want to search by title for example, just add an exposed filter for the title and select "contains".
3. If you want to search by more fields which is likely, add the fields you want to search by (and maybe hide them) eg. Node title / Body. Then create a `Global: Combine fields filter (exposed)` and select the above fields with "contains".

That will let you search whichever fields but just not as nicely as with the search module.

If anyone else has a solution to the exposed search problem, post please.

Comment: I already tried that before (see my updated question) sorry, should have mentioned...

Comment: I've edited my answer.. Pretty strange overall but I got a hacky way of doing it.

Comment: Okay I will try that - how do I do the second step? do I need to add the title  to the fields section? (I will probably just need those searchable as that will lead to the content anyway!)

Comment: If you're only searching the title, you just need to add an exposed "contains" filter for title. Whether or not you add or display it as a field shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have added title to the 'filter criteria' as per your suggestion (http://i.imgur.com/peIEXoJ.png) but no results appear... - I personally think OG is a really badly made module...!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the entire View settings.. I had it working so it should be possible on your end.

Comment: (upvote for great helping spirit!) Here is my main view page, my title ‘exposed’ settings and my content type settings which has the ‘title’ as a field
(just to make sure I’m doing the right thing when testing and search results should appear!)  
http://imgur.com/a/Tmq2e

Comment: A few ideas but don't worry, it will definitely work eventually. 1. Your screenshot of the content type was cut off after a few fields.. Do you have an og_group_ref field in Article? 2. In your screenshot for the view, it's currently a page and not a block meaning either all or no results depending on the set up. (No group id available) 3. If you do have a block view, what "default value" do you provide for the contextual filter? 4. Before searching, does the view provide the list of organic group content to search from?

Comment: This is my whole view: http://i.imgur.com/iRPoDOd.png
1. Yes og_group_ref is on all my content types: http://i.imgur.com/2D0GYCs.png
2. Its a page because it was a page in the tutorial too! - Do I need to add a block view?
3. Related to the answer above I have added a block and have the following on my continual filter view: http://i.imgur.com/k5ac4ej.png
4. Yes it does, but is it meant to show it?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the search filter.. Only leave the exposed filter for title / body. And in your contextual filter, change it to "Provide Default": Current Og Node from Context..

Comment: If I remove the search filter where is the search box for the user to use? - I have only added the title in my filter but the  Current Og Node from Context "Provide Default" doesn't appear in my contextual filters (http://imgur.com/a/02Nim) might be easier if you upload a picture of the view to avoid further confusion...

Comment: You need to expose the title filter for it to appear and Ajax has to be enabled for it to appear in the preview. The "provide default OG" thing isn't appearing because you're still on a page view. Switch to a block.l

Comment: This might make more sense of I explain it.. Organic groups work by having children nodes reference parent group nodes. The contextual filter provides the view with the current url's node id. The view then searches the database for all children nodes referencing that urls id. So when you create the view and make a block, you then place it on a group's page to show all of the group content.

Comment: Looks like we are making progress!!!
I have selected ‘yes’ on Ajax, I have changed to a block view and I have removed the search in the filter criteria and added the content title exposed filter instead.
I am getting a sort of search function in the preview (which works!)


Also in the relationship I am getting OG membership from Node - (I guess I should select the ‘Node group’ one as that one is probably the one created by me...

However I am still not getting the "provide default OG" from the group ID contextual filter!

http://imgur.com/a/RbL89

Comment: Ah, you need to enable the organic groups context module for it to appear. And i don't think you actually need either relationship in this view. Try it with only the contextual filter. And I'm pretty sure the "node group" one is to show the group content of groups in the current group. Like one level deeper if you know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks it works! - So I guess because I have added the Relationship and Contextual Filters to this view it can only be used as a block on a organic view page - is that correct? (I have added the block to my 'Search' Content Type and no results appear - which is a bit of a shame!) One last question (promise!): is there a way to only show the results once a search term has been entered --- It currently shows all content pages of that group under the search bar... http://i.imgur.com/SpxteIk.png

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it! - Added 'input required' under exposed form --- However It would be extremely nice and useful if this block can also work if placed outside of the OG page but still keep the same settings (i.e. search only within the user's group content!) Maybe I can clone that block and change a few settings on it to do so...

Answer (score 3):

## Group module as possible OG alternative

As per your (3rd) comment like "I personally think OG is ..." below the previous answer: be aware that the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module is a possible alternative for [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) for Drupal 7 these days (and soon Drupal 8 also ...).

Refer to my answer to "[How to create basic Organic Groups functionality with flags and references?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29033/how-to-create-basic-organic-groups-functionality-with-flags-and-references/190305#190305)" for way more details about the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module.

Specific to this question here, some more details about the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, as mentioned on "[Group - an alternative to Organic Groups](https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/group-alternative-organic-groups)":

> **Permission system**
>
> Group permissions are defined by the site builder and are then passed onto every group instance. This is done by configuring the “group type”, which is comparable to a node type for nodes. So you can configure a set of permissions for different types of groups, yet don’t have to worry about group members being able to fiddle with them.
>
> **Group roles**
>
> In order to make the above work, the Group module defines a concept called group roles. These behave exactly like user roles would globally, but can be defined on the group type level. Group provides three special roles to make your life easier too: Anonymous (no account on the site), Outsider (account on the site but not a member of the group) and Member (account on the site and a member of the group).

So with the above in mind, if you're willing to consider the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module as a possible alternative, restricting the search results as you are trying to do seems much easier (if not automatically).

## Search configuration module for more configuration options

Another approach (which you might possibly want to combine with using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module) is to use the [Search configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config) module. Some details from its project page:

> This module has five main functions.
>
> 1. Alter the appearance of the core node search form.
> 2. Group content types for more meaningful searching.
> 3. Restrict search results by the content type. This is a role based restriction.
> 4. Restrict search results from showing individual items.
> 5. Alter the pager limit (aka number search item results per page).

Its project page contains many more details about what you can do with this module.